# Injecting a bean in a Security Filter (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-security, spring-bean

Before the login, I added a filter that checks if a the computer name is registered in the database. For this, I inject a repository in the filter. The problem is that it marks the bean as null, and I read the filter and the bean are in different contexts.

How can I inject the bean in the filter?

This is the bean injection

```
@Qualifier("simpleRepo")
    @Autowired
    private SimpleRepo simpleRepo;
```

And this is the method where I wanna use the methods of the repository

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        response.setContentType("text/html");


        String computerName = null;
        String remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        try {
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(remoteAddress);
            computerName = inetAddress.getHostName();

            if (computerName.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost")) {
                computerName = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        }

        Response response_query = new Response();

        System.out.println("computerName: " + computerName);

        response_query = simpleRepo.isARegisteredMachine(computerName);

        System.out.println(response_query.getStatus());

        //httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/signin");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: What does "and I read the filter and the bean are in different contexts" mean? Can you provide more details about your app configuration?